# asp.net mvc multitenant database per login error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an app for our company which needs to have separate database per client. App is for the usage of other multiple companies, so the app needs to identify the company name when the user logs in and make the users operate only within their company db. I have it all set, but the problem is that the app is not able to handle many different databases simultaneously. When users from more different companies log in, the first users db gets changed to the db of the second user who is logged in! This is of course unacceptable. How can I make the app to use many dbs simultaneously?

I have one database which collects all app users and their company names and separate databases for each company. I also have a standard asp below are my codes:
My applicatinon dbcontext is

```
  public static string _DbName;

        public ApplicationDbContext() : base(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConString.dbCatlogConn) ? "DefaultConnection" : ConString.dbCatlogConn, throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            this.Database.CommandTimeout = 600;
        }
        public ApplicationDbContext(string dbName) : base(dbName)
        {
            _DbName = dbName;
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
```

Login class and database initializer in account controller

```
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return View(model);
                    }

                    var regx = new Regex("[-]");
                    if (!regx.IsMatch(userdash))
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Error";
                        return View();
                    }

                    string x = model.UserName.ToLower();
                    Session["Initial"] = x.Split('-').First();


                       var dbcompanies = db.CompanyLists.Where(t => (t.InitializationLetters == Session["Initial"].ToString())).Select(t => new { ConnString = t.ConnectionString }).ToList();

                        if (dbcompanies.Count > 0)
                        {

                            if (dbcompanies[0].ConnString == "")
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Session["ConnectionString"] = dbcompanies[0].ConnString;

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {


                            ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "en" ? "Invalid login attempt." : "text here");
                            return View(model);
                        }




                if (Session["ConnectionString"].ToString() == "" || Session["ConnectionString"].ToString() == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message1 = "notfound";
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {

                    using ( db = new ApplicationDbContext(Session["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
                    {

                        UserManager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
                        var user = db.Users.Where(e => e.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                        var result = new SignInStatus();
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            result = SignInStatus.Failure;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string dbPassword = dal.DecryptPassword(user.AnotherUsername, user.AnotherSalt, user.PasswordHash);
                            var status = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(dbPassword, model.Password);
                            if (status == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                            {
                               result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, user.PasswordHash, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
                            }
                            else
                                result = SignInStatus.Failure;

                        }

                        switch (result)
                        {
                            case SignInStatus.Success:

                                if (user != null)
                                {
                                    if (user.Disabled == true)
                                    {
                                        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                                        ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "en" ? "Invalid login attempt." : "text");
                                        return View(model);
                                        //return View("Lockout");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                                        user.LastIpAddress = ip;
                                        db.SaveChanges();
                                        if (User.IsInRole(UsersTypes.Interview.ToString()))
                                        {
                                            return RedirectToRoute("profile", new { type = profile.Acceptance });
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                                return View("Lockout");
                            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                            case SignInStatus.Failure:
                            default:


                                ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "en" ? "Invalid login attempt." : "error");
                                return View(model);

                        } 
                    }

                }
```

I have found the same problem here  [asp.net mvc multitenant database per tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954745/asp-net-mvc-multitenant-database-per-tenant)

when I run i got error DbName cant to be null where should I declare or pass the database connection for that variable and will it be the main database?

I have also used the string literal as one of the comments like this one

```
 private const string DbName = "default app connection string";
```

but I got error It must be variable or indexer

can I find help for that problem